# ESRI Javascript API pan parameters

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, distance, pan

Using the ESRI javasript API, is there a way to set the distance the map will move when panning?  When I fire the map.panUp(), for example, it pans, but about twice as far as I would like it to.

Comment: i think it is going to be a function of the display width converted to map distance.

Comment: This is probably more of a pain, but you could download the JS and dig through ESRI's code to see how it is calculated.  If you don't like it, then modify it and reference a copy on your webserver instead of ESRI's.

Comment: Do you also want to change the behaviour of the pan navigation buttons, or just what happens when you call the API's panUp function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its not possible to get control over pan behavior in the JSAPI directly, but Ryan Mordoff wrote a really cool plugin and shared it on [Github](https://github.com/rymor/esri-kinetic-panning).

i think most people are using it to increase the default multiplier, but you could also use it to achieve the inverse.

see [this](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/60262) thread for more info.